# Whats ODIN mode in Galaxy Tab 2?

Tags: odin, samsung-galaxy-tab-2-7

I just pressed the power button and the volume up button in my Tab. I went into a screen called ODIN mode... It started downloading something... What is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the *download firmware* mode.

It can be used to upgrade official firmware via Samsung's own Odin software (or the 3rd party [heimdall](https://github.com/Benjamin-Dobell/Heimdall) (also [here](http://www.glassechidna.com.au/products/heimdall/))). It's also used to install a custom aftermarket firmware like [CyanogenMod](http://cyanogenmod.com). Actually it allows more but installing firmware is the most common use.

Comment: any guide on how to install official firmware through this?

Comment: [SamFirmware](http://www.sammobile.com/firmware/) has official images. I'm however not sure how to install them because I only prefer aftermarket firmwares (Cyanogenmod or pure AOSP Android) to manufacturer branded versions. See also this explanation page on [XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_S_Series#Download_Mode). Howto: [S2](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_S_II:_Full_Update_Guide) or [S3](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_S_III:_Full_Update_Guide) or see CM's [wiki](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/wiki/Samsung) for more Samsung devices.

Comment: You sure SamMobile is genuine firmware?

Comment: It seems to get cited very often. It's definitely not a rogue site but also not an official Samsung site either. If you're new to flashing alternative firmwares, just stay away. Your question seemed to come from curiousity (by stumbling upon the odin mode).

Comment: I have already rooted my phone but not sure about the tablet... its new and already samsung provide updates... I have doubts whether to switch to CM :)

Comment: Yeah, difficult to answer. Info: CM9 hit RC2 yesterday and CM10 is gaining traction lately, you might enjoy Jelly Bean soon. I'm not sure about the firmware status for the GT2, though.