# Flashing Galaxy Tab 2 7.0 (Verizon branded)

Tags: rom-flashing, downloading

We are attempting to flash a Galaxy Tab 2 7.0 (Verizon branded) with a cutom ROM.  We get to the following screen:

[image]

Followed by

[image]

First, where is it looking to download?

Second, why is it hanging?

Stuck and looking for some guidance here.

***Edit***

I found this post that points to a locked bootloader:
[Root and Unlock Bootloader on Galaxy Tab 2 7.0 (Verizon)](http://smartphones.wonderhowto.com/how-to/root-and-unlock-bootloader-samsung-galaxy-tab-2-7-0-4g-lte-from-verizon-0139896/)

***Edit 2***

Following the aforementioned post:

I get this error on the Odin console..

```
<ID:0/006> Added!!
<OSM> Enter CS for MD5..
<OSM> Check MD5.. Do not unplug the cable..
<OSM> Please wait..
<OSM> CF-Auto-Root-espressorf-espressorfxx-gtp3100.tar.md5 is valid.
<OSM> Checking MD5 finished Sucessfully..
<OSM> Leave CS..
<ID:0/006> Odin v.3 engine (ID:6)..
<ID:0/006> File analysis..
<ID:0/006> SetupConnection..
<ID:0/006> Initialzation..
<ID:0/006> Get PIT for mapping..
<ID:0/006> Firmware update start..
<ID:0/006> recovery.img
<ID:0/006> NAND Write Start!! 
<ID:0/006> FAIL! (Auth)
<OSM> All threads completed. (succeed 0 / failed 1)
```

Comment: What steps/guide (if any) are you attempting to follow? What are you expecting to happen when you go past the warning? It's not "hanging", it's waiting for you to flash your ROM. Related: [Whats ODIN mode in Galaxy Tab 2?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/26155/whats-odin-mode-in-galaxy-tab-2)

Comment: @eldarerathis I am trying to enumerate the device with adb fastboot so that I can upload the ROM I have compiled, but the device is not showing up.  I am not following any guides because I have not found one for the GT2 7.0

Comment: I don't think the Tab 2 has fastboot support. You'll probably have to install the ROM via either a custom recovery or Odin/Heimdall. A generic "how to root" guide can probably help you get a recovery installed. Might start by looking into that: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1900055

Comment: Thanks for the link. :^) I will check it out.  It's been a long day and will pick this up in the morning.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to root/flash a custom ROM to a Verizon GT2 but I see GT2 3100 in the code. You are not using the correct ODIN files. I'm no expert but I know the Verizon Tab is different from the WiFi Tab. Luckily you didn't lock it up.

Comment: Yes.  We actually figured that out, but I have not updated this post to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

Galaxy Tab 2 is not bootloader-locked. You can directly flash the images. Just write the partition name and drag the file in command-line using Heimdall.